# Is there a way to get a border around image with Lazy Load plugin?

Tags: lazy-loading

I am using this plugin for lazy loading of images.

http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy

It loads my 80 images very nicely. This is the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Lazy Load</title>
<script src="jquery/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.lazy/jquery.lazy.min.js"></script>
<style>
.border {
border: 5px solid red;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<script>    
$(function() {
    $('.lazy').lazy({
      effect: "fadeIn",
      effectTime: 2000,
      threshold: 0
    });
});
</script>

<img class="lazy border" data-src="images/1.jpg" />
<img class="lazy border" data-src="images/80.jpg" />
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to add a border around each image but that border do not load as nicely as the image. Can someone please tell me how to add elements (div, css) to the images so they load as smooth as only the image do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured it out and want to share my solution. I am using afterLoad to add my border.

```
<script>    
$(function() {
    $('.lazy').lazy({
      effect: "fadeIn",
      effectTime: 2000,
      threshold: 0,
      afterLoad: function(element) {                   
            element.css('border', '10px solid chartreuse');                  
        }
    });
});
</script>
```